# Turning off a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ not connected to Mac

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+

I've seen lots of questions about safely turning off the Raspberry Pi but I haven't found what I'm looking for.

My Raspberry Pi is connected directly to the power adapter and not to my laptop.

What is the safe way of turning it off in that case?

Comment: There are many answers. Either execute a shutdown command or connect a shutdown button. What have you tried and why are none of these OK?

Comment: Thanks. I'm under time pressure because I'm moving and need to take it with me in the next hours. I don't have experience with the Raspberry Pi (got my first one yesterday) so creating a button seems non viable atm. The shutdown command could work but how do run it when I'm not connected to it?

Comment: Also, not sure if relevant but the pi is running [Homebridge](https://homebridge.io/raspberry-pi-image)

Comment: If you can't connect to the Pi how do you use it? If it is new you won't lose much if you just turn it off.

Comment: I booted the Homebridge OS into the MicroSD card and that's all i've done so far. It creates a local page to access for smart home automation, etc. Good point, I just didn't want to create any problems beyond loss of data.